# Why does the Rich Text Box freeze when loading a large string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, colors, richtextbox, performance

I have a program where I basically need to load Rich Text from a StringBuilder.
The problem is, somethimes I get a string that is 100,000 lines long (and this is a possible situation for the program), including Rtf codes and colours.

The problem isn't building the string, it's when I asign the Rtf property to the StringBuilder.ToString(), it takes a solid **4 minutes** to load.

```
TextBox.Rtf = Build.ToString();
```

If I copy this same string from the StringBuilder, and load it in WordPad, it takes about **2 or 3 seconds**. I am diabling the RTB's redrawing by using SendMessage() and WM_SETREDRAW, but that doesn't change anything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RichTextBox` uses `riched20.dll` which is the `v3.0` of the library `Rich Edit Control` of [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com). However, WordPad uses `msfedit.dll` which is version `4.1`.

Version `4.1` is about 30 times more faster than `v3.0`

See this for more information about versions
[MSDN About Rich Edit Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787873%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the RTB control is not gonna cut 10,000 lines, nevermind 100,000.

One possible way to optimize it, is to load from a file or stream instead, but I dont suspect much improvement.

Comment: Then how does WordPad do it in 2-3 **seconds**?

Comment: @Miguel, I suspect WordPad does not use an RTB control.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but could it be that the **GC** (garbage collector) gets triggered? That shouldn't last 4 minutes though...